# Run testcontainers in Bitbucket

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

I am adding [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) to my integration tests. Locally everything works fine. To let it run on my Bitbucket Pipelines, I created following (simplified) [bitbucket-pipeline](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/bitbucket_pipelines/).yml:

```
image: maven:3.6.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      caches:
        - maven
      script:
        - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
        - mvn -B verify
  branches:
    master:
     - step:
       caches:
         - maven
       services:
         - docker
       script:
         - ..
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
```

But when the pipeline starts running and the tests are executed, the docker service seems non existent:

```
Container startup failed
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=postgres:12.4, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

Comment: Could you add the whole log section with that exception, please?

Also, do you know how is docker env set up in bitbucket? Like is it connecting to remote or local docker daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite embarrassing. I forgot to add the

```
services:
     - docker
```

part to the default pipeline. So, as the logging showed, there was no docker service running for the non 'master' branches.

Comment: For what its worth I did exactly the same :)